# Young adult book about a girl that ends up in a magical land

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I have recently been on holidays and read a chapter in this young adult book and now I can't remember what it's called. I also read it in German which means finding it in English is even harder.

There is a young boy, who works in the guard (I think) in this magical land , and he is a stable boy or something. He is chosen by a bird of prey - not sure what it is called. I think the magical land is in the middle of war because of a drought.

There is a girl in the "real world", and she drives her scooter or bicycle through a storm home and I think she gets a talisman from her Irish grandmother as a present.

This is all I have - I think the title was something like "the prophetess of the rain".

I have searched high and low for this book and even tried to contact the hotel but no one could help :(

Answer (score 3):

Could this be "Light of the Oracle" (2005) by Victoria Hanley?

> This companion novel to The Seer and the Sword (2000) and The Healer's Keep (2002, both Holiday House) stands very well on its own. **Bryn, a poor stonecutter's daughter, is recruited to become a handmaiden in the Temple of the Oracle**. There she will be tutored in the ways of prophecy and might possibly be chosen as a priestess. Entering the Temple at the same time is Clea, a spoiled rich girl who becomes Bryn's nemesis. Kiran, a horse trainer who can communicate with animals and is a priesthood candidate, is immediately attracted to Bryn. **To be a priest or priestess, one must first be chosen by a bird**. Clea is "bird chosen" by a vulture, which gives her the power to cast curses. Bryn, however, is chosen, not by a bird, but by the wind, which means that her powers of prophecy are great. Intrigue and treachery abound within the Temple grounds